# MSCharts on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mschart, blacklight

I tried integrating MSCharts in a WPF application which uses Blacklight as the UI library (For the most part). Performance is much slower and incompatibility is apparent. You guys know any better way? MSCharts capabilities in WPF!

Comment: did you found any good chart? if yes please suggest me it...i also looking for the same...looking for chart With rich functionality for SilverLight Application but doesn't found ...also looking for how to use mschart in silverlight.....thank you so much

Comment: @Pritesh, I could not integrate MSCharts with WPF well. So used WPF Toolkit and its charting library instead. You will need to go through it and will need to change the look and feel to suit your needs. There are a number of questions I posted on this in SO and I hope they will be of use for you. Also you will be able to find a fair amount of online references too. Good luck.

Comment: picmate Thank you so much for replying.

Answer (score 4):

What sort of charting requirements do you have? The WPF / Silverlight Toolkit charts have been demonstrated to be very slow:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/12/visiblox-visifire-dynamicdatadisplay-charting-performance-comparison/

However, there are alternatives. [Visiblox](http://www.visiblox.com/) provides a high performance chart for WPF.

Comment: Hi ColinE, Thanks for the answer. I am looking at some free WPF charting resources to integrate in to a dashboard tool. WPF toolkit charts are not as rich as MSCharts(?, at least until I saw it last)

Comment: @picmate ya exactly.. toolkit of WPF and SilverLight doesn't contain chart with rich Functionality so i also looking for how to use MSChart in silverlight or any opensource or free chart control which contain functionality like  zooming,paning,Annotation,DrilDown,Selection etc..

Comment: @Pritesh, you may need to customize WPF toolkit to a certain degree to have drill down etc. effects.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think MSCharts are compatible with WPF. From the [MSChart download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=130F7986-BF49-4FE5-9CA8-910AE6EA442C&displaylang=en)

> ASP.NET and Windows Forms Chart Controls for .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

You would be better off looking at the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) and the [Extended WPF Toolkit](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/). This has controls specifically designed for WPF to take advantage of all the features available.

Comment: Hi ChrisF, Thanks for your quick response. I looked at the WPF toolkit, but not the extended one. What I need is to unleash the same power of MSCharts in a wpf context for a BI dashboard.

Comment: @picmate - I've not done a detailed comparison either (as I've not had to). If the WPF Toolkit doesn't do what you need then you might need to go with some other commercial controls such as Telerik or Infragistics.

Comment: Thanks again ChrisF. As far as I can see the only other solution is to enhance the WPFToolkit charts to suite our needs. Do let me know if you know of any resources which I can use to make WPFCharts more productive.